# Two transits in Schengen area

Tags: schengen, transit-visas, layovers

Do I need a transit visa if I am travelling from Marrakech to Oakland, California, with connections in Oslo, Norway and Barcelona, Spain. I have a 12-hour layover in Oslo and a 2-hour layover in Barcelona. I am a Moroccan passport holder and I am a US permanent resident.

Comment: You need a Schengen short-stay visa, that is, a type C visa, because you will pass through Schengen entry controls in Oslo and Schengen exit controls in Barcelona.  An airport transit visa (type A) is insufficient because it does not allow you to pass through passport control; type B transit visas were abolished some years ago.  If you could fly directly to Barcelona, you would not need a visa because you would not need to enter the Schengen area.  You would also save a lot of time!

Comment: Oslo is definitely not in Sweden.

Comment: @dda that assertion was the result of a faulty edit, not a mistake on the part of Allal arroud.

Comment: @Giorgio please be more careful when you edit questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the flight between Oslo and Barcelona is a Schengen internal flight which from an immigration point of view is treated like a domestic flight. So you will have to enter the Schengen area in Oslo and leave it in Barcelona.

An airside transit visa is no use to you because you have to enter the area. The Schengen area no longer issues landside transit visas. Therefore you will need a regular short stay Schengen Visa.